# unable to insert text at a particular line of a file using linux sed

Tags: linux, sed

I want to replace the 2nd line of a file using linux sed using these following commands.

```
sed -i"" '2d' /usr/local/services/status.sh
sed -i '2i\testing' /usr/local/services/status.sh
```

Is there any error in my command? I can't find out.
Is there any other way to do it?

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace 2nd line:

```
$ cat file
AIX
Unix
Linux
$ sed -i '2s/.*/testing/' file
$ cat file
AIX
testing
Linux
```

To insert before the 2nd line:

```
$ sed -i '2i testing' file
```

To use a variable as part of subtitution:

```
$ PID=2456
$ sed -i "2s/.*/testing $PID/" file
```

Comment: thanks a ton. 
Could you tell me how to concatenate two strings in between /.*/____/?

e.g: i need to save the PID along with the text.

Comment: e.g: i need to save the PID along with the text.something like this-

sed -i '2s/.*/ps -p $! > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo 1 running || echo 1 not running'

Please correct me.

Comment: see the update..first store the PID in a separate variable and then use the variable in the sed command.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed -i '2c\testing' file
```